# How to I start contributing to Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I want to fix some issues with rvm and Aptana Studio 3. Is there a CONTRIBUTING.md somewhere I can use to bootstrap my environment to develop the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Aptana mantains their repos at [github](https://github.com/aptana). Also, you can search in the [tracker](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD) if there is any item related to your issue open, or open a new one yourself asking for help.